# How to Regex replace characters at the end of a string

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have an issue in Java when trying to remove the characters from the end of a string. This has now become a generic pattern match issue that I cannot resolve.

PROBLEM = remove all pluses, minuses and spaces (not bothered about whitespace) from the end of a string.

```
Pattern myRegex;
Matcher myMatch;
String myPattern = "";
String myString = "";
String myResult = "";

myString="surname; forename--+  + --++   "
myPattern="^(.*)[-+ ]*$"
//expected result = "surname; forename"
myRegex = Pattern.compile(myPattern);
myMatch = myRegex.matcher(myString);

if (myMatch.find( )) {
    myResult = myMatch.group(1);
} else {
    myResult = myString;
}
```

The only way I can get this to work is by reversing the string and reversing the pattern match, then I reverse the result to get the right answer!

Comment: Try this regex "^(.*?)[-+ ]*$" instead. I added a `?` to make the `*` non-greedy.

Comment: Probably something like `myString.replaceAll("[-+ ]+$", "")`

Comment: @redneb: Yes, a greedy `.*` at the beginning would eat the whole string.

Comment: You should do what @Thilo said. Read my comment to understand why your approach failed and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In the following pattern:

```
^(.*)[-+ ]*$
```

... the `.*` is a greedy match. This means that it will match as many characters as possible while still allowing the entire pattern to match.

You need to change it to non-greedy by adding `?`.

```
^(.*?)[-+ ]*$
```

Comment: thanks - I can now reclaim those months I lost off the end of my life!

I did notice greedy matches when I was reading up on this issue but it obviously didn't register with me.

And for those wanting a simpler way for this particular replace ...

myString.replaceAll("(\\+|\\-| )*$","")